# Webpack with dynamic entries

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-encore

I am attempting to dynamically load JS files with webpack to make it easier to add whitelabel customers. Currently I have to keep updating the webpack config to manually add their files each time but I want to set this to a dynamic method so I can just add the JS file(s) when needed and not to worry about the webpack.

My script in webpack.config.js

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var DelWebpackPlugin = require('del-webpack-plugin');
var fs = require('fs');

 //This is how we used to do it before we implemented whitelabels.
 Encore
     .setOutputPath('web/build/')
     .setPublicPath('/build')
     .enableVersioning()

     .autoProvideVariables({
         $: 'jquery',
         jQuery: 'jquery',
         'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })

     .addPlugin(new DelWebpackPlugin({
         info: true,
         include: ['**.*']
     }))

     .addEntry('app', './assets/app/js/global.js')
     .addEntry('client1', './assets/app/js/whitelabels/client1.js')
     .addEntry('client2', './assets/app/js/whitelabels/client2.js')

     .enableSassLoader()

     .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
 ;
  module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Each client has their own js in the folder whitelabels. My goal is to not have to maintain the webpack config each time we add a new whitelabel customer.

Below is my attempt when trying to dynamically load files.

```
var whitelabels = './assets/app/js/whitelabels';
var list = [];

fs.readdir(whitelabels, function(err, items) {
    items.forEach(item => {

        Encore
            .setOutputPath('web/build/')
            .setPublicPath('/build')
            .enableVersioning()
            .autoProvideVariables({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
            })
            .addPlugin(new DelWebpackPlugin({
                info: true,
                include: ['**.*']
            }))
            .addEntry(item.replace('.js', ''), './assets/app/js/whitelabels/'+ item)
            .enableSassLoader()
            .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction());

        const otherConfigs = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
        otherConfigs.name = item;
        list.push(otherConfigs);
        Encore.reset();
    })
});
// export the final configuration
module.exports = list;
```

However no matter what I try it keeps giving me the following error

```
Running webpack ...

/Volumes/git/project/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:212
            outputOptions.context = firstOptions.context;
                                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of undefined
    at processOptions (/Volumes/git/project/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:212:41)
    at yargs.parse (/Volumes/git/project/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:397:2)
    at Object.Yargs.self.parse (/Volumes/git/project/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:533:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/git/project/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:152:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Dump of Encore.getWebpackConfig();

```
{ context: '/Volumes/git/project',
  entry:
   { 
     app: './assets/app/js/global.js',
     client1: './assets/app/js/whitelabels/client1.js',
     client2: './assets/app/js/whitelabels/client2.js' },
  output:
   { path: '/Volumes/git/project/web/build',
     filename: '[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
     publicPath: '/build/',
     pathinfo: true },
  module: { rules: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  plugins:
   [ ExtractTextPlugin {
       filename: '[name].[contenthash:8].css',
       id: 2,
       options: [Object] },
     DeleteUnusedEntriesJSPlugin { entriesToDelete: [] },
     ManifestPlugin { opts: [Object] },
     LoaderOptionsPlugin { options: [Object] },
     NamedModulesPlugin { options: {} },
     WebpackChunkHash {
       algorithm: 'md5',
       digest: 'hex',
       additionalHashContent: [Function] },
     ProvidePlugin { definitions: [Object] },
     DefinePlugin { definitions: [Object] },
     FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin {
       compilationSuccessInfo: [Object],
       onErrors: undefined,
       shouldClearConsole: false,
       formatters: [Array],
       transformers: [Array] },
     AssetOutputDisplayPlugin { outputPath: 'web/build', 
     friendlyErrorsPlugin: [Object] },
     DelWebpackPlugin { options: [Object] } ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  performance: { hints: false },
  stats:
   { hash: false,
     version: false,
     timings: false,
     assets: false,
     chunks: false,
     maxModules: 0,
     modules: false,
     reasons: false,
     children: false,
     source: false,
     errors: false,
     errorDetails: false,
     warnings: false,
     publicPath: false },
  resolve:
   { extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx', '.vue', '.ts', '.tsx' ],
     alias: {} },
  externals: {} }
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work

```js
var Encore = require("@symfony/webpack-encore");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var DelWebpackPlugin = require("del-webpack-plugin");
var fs = require("fs");

var whitelabels = "./assets/app/js/whitelabels";

Encore
  .setOutputPath("web/build/")
  .setPublicPath("/build")
  .enableVersioning()
  .autoProvideVariables({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
  })
  .addPlugin(
    new DelWebpackPlugin({
      info: true,
      include: ["**.*"]
    })
  )
  .addEntry("app", "./assets/app/js/global.js");

fs.readdir(whitelabels, function(err, items) {
  items.forEach(item => {
    Encore.addEntry(item.replace(".js", ""), "./assets/app/js/whitelabels/" + item)
  });
});

Encore
  .enableSassLoader()
  .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction());

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Comment: Doing this does not seem to be picking up any of the whitelabels sadly. For some reason it seems to be completely skipping anything in the foreach loop. However when I console log the items variable I can see all the .js files inside the folder.

Comment: @killstreet There was a mistake, I've updated the code. Can you please try now?

Comment: Sadly even this seems to fail. It won't throw any errors but it won't actually run the added files which are in the loop :(

Comment: I have updated my question with a dump of Encore.getWebpackConfig(), however it all looks quite right to me...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use synchron methods.

```
  var whitelabels = "./assets/app/js/whitelabels";
  var items=fs.readdirSync(whitelabels);
  items.forEach(item => {
       Encore.addEntry(item.replace(".js", ""), "./assets/app/js/whitelabels/" + item)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this - you have to adapt the glob pattern and the paths to fit your needs. The "chalk" plugin is not necessary, you can remove it - I added it for nicer output.

The key is, that you have to add it synchronously (like with `glob.sync` in this example).

```
const chalk = require('chalk');
const glob = require("glob");
const path = require('path');

// add all components recursively as Encore entry
const entryPoints = glob.sync('**/index.js', {
  'cwd': './your/entrypoints/folder'
});

entryPoints.forEach((file) => {
  const filePath = './your/entrypoints/folder/' + file;
  const name = file.replace(/\/index\.js/, '');
  console.log(`adding entry ${chalk.green(name)} located at ${chalk.green(filePath)}`);
  Encore.addEntry(name, filePath);
});
```